# Google Maps Kit. Whether some external point lieing on the drawn route from A to B

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For example, in the Google Map Kit for iOS I have a two points, those are start point A, and destination point B and route drawn between them. Suppose that there is some external point C. I need to know whether point C lieing(included) on the route between A and B or not.

Comment: Have you looked at GMSGeometryContainsLocation (CLLocationCoordinate2D point, GMSPath *path, BOOL geodesic)? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/group___geometry_utils

Comment: A what is GMSPath, is it route between point A and B ? or can I somehow convert my drawn route to GMSPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thanks to all of you. I'have already found the solution. When you make a request like a draw route between A and B, GMapKit returns json, with the following format `routes[legs[steps[...]]]`. So steps[] contains each step existing in the route, it is straight line actually from one point to another. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=ru#Steps. So, my solution is to compare sought point's lat and long with lat and longs of each step in the route.